# .NET multi target frameworks copies System.* DLLs to .NET Framework output directory

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.7.2, .net-standard-2.1

I've got a .NET project that targets multiple frameworks, i.e.,
`<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.1;net472</TargetFrameworks>`

The project contains NuGet packages that bring in System.* dependencies like `System.Memory` and `System.Buffers`.

When I build the project it creates two output directories, `netstandard2.1` and `net472`, which is fine.

The bit I'm struggling to understand is why does the `net472` output directory contain the System.* dependencies? I understand them being copied to the `netstandard2.1` directory, but why are they copied for the .NET Framework directory when they can be loaded from the .NET Framework installation on the machine (i.e., GAC)?

Is there a way to exclude System.* dlls when for the `net472` target?

Comment: Usually, the compiler is right about what he's doing here. The version he copies to the net472 folder are typically newer than the ones in the GAC. It is possible that the compiler uses .netstandard files in .net framework this way. If you don't get any runtime errors, all is fine.

Comment: is the question now answered? in this case [you can accept my reply as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to "close" the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is ok, as both are nuget packages that are not part of .net framework (yellow instead of green)

[image]

[image]

so they need to be copied to output.

Everything is fine.

Comment: Thanks. How come when I try to add them as a reference to a pure .NET Framework project, they exist under the Assemblies section?

Comment: I just had a few minutes to test it and this is a caching thing, I don't see anything in add reference as I haven't done this for my test project. I get the 2 DLLs in net framework 4.7.2 output, BUT not in NS2.1 as expected.